# what are the uses of case 'inside's in verilog ? is it synthesizable?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

in verilog, we have case 'inside's. what are the usages of that & is it synthesizable?

eg :

```
case(in) inside
  4'b0000, 4'b00?1: ; // 0 and 1,3
  [5:7]: ; // 5,6,7
  default: ;
endcase
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Verilog you don't have `case` `inside` - that is *SystemVerilog*. In *Verilog*, if you want wildcards in your `case` statement, you have to use either `casez` or `casex`. In a `casez` statement, a `Z` means don't care; in a `casex` statement, a `Z` or an `X` means don't care, eg

```
casez (in)
  4'b0000, 4'b00z1: ; // 0 and 1,3
  4'b0101, 4'b0110, 4'b0111: ; // 5,6,7
  default: ;
endcase
```

or, because a `?` is an exact synonym for `Z`:

```
casez (in)
  4'b0000, 4'b00?1: ; // 0 and 1,3
  4'b0101, 4'b0110, 4'b0111: ; // 5,6,7
  default: ;
endcase
```

or, with `casex`:

```
casez (in)
  4'b0000, 4'b00x1: ; // 0 and 1,3
  4'b0101, 4'b0110, 4'b0111: ; // 5,6,7
  default: ;
endcase
```

SystemVerilog added `case` `inside`, which is better, because it allows *ranges* to be used (like in your original example):

```
  [5:7]: ; // 5,6,7
```

and because it is *asymmetrical*. Using `casex` is the second biggest sin in Verilog (second to using ordered port mapping). This is because `casex` is *symmetrical* (as is `casez`). By this, I mean that with `casex` an `X` in the input expression (`in` in your example) also means don't care, which means that if the input expression goes to `X` then all branches match (and the first is executed because the first matching branch is executed in a Verilog `case` statement). The result of this is that if a net or variable goes to `X`, `casex` will filter it out rather than propagating it, which means a bug might get hidden. This does not happen with `case` `inside`, because an `X` (or `Z`) in the input expression *does not* mean don't care (that's what I mean by it being *asymmetrical*).

So, you would use `case` `inside` anywhere you want a `case` statement with wildcards or ranges. And yes - it is synthesisable.

---

`casez` is considered safer in Verilog, because it is unlikely that an input expression would spuriously go to `Z`.

Comment: A nice little hack in Verliog is to use casez(in | ‘h0). ORing a high-Z with 0 results in an X. Allows one to use wildcards in case statements, while still propagating high-Z and X as unknowns during simulation. Synthesis will disregard the superfluous OR with 0